# How to add values to dynamic(?) map in velocity?

Tags: velocity

I have the following velocity code.

```
#foreach($content in $list)
   #set($map = {$content.categoryName:[]})

   #foreach($child in $children)
      // I want to add values to $map.$content.categoryName
   #end
#end
```

I would like to add values to `$map.$content.categoryName`. I tried

```
$map.$content.categoryName.add(values here)
```

but it didn't work. I also tried

```
$map[$content.categoryName].add(values here)
```

But it still didn't work. Could someone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's java, not javascript:

$map.get($content.categoryName).add($child.value)

Comment: No :)  But i'm just very used to people confusing the two in both syntax and server vs client side render-time.  So i make totally uncalled-for assumptions like that sometimes.  My apologies!

Comment: // no..no need to apologies. I just looked up my question and i was like.. "oh..did I post a wrong question..?"

Comment: Actually, you are adding values to a list, not a map.  The map just happens to be in a map.